# An object in heap riddle

Tags: c#, heap-memory

In the code below `ViewState["L"]` stores a `List<string>`. I create a new instance of `List` and assign the casted value of a viewstate to it.

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();

myList=(List<string>)ViewState["L"];

Response.Write(myList.Equals(ViewState["L"]));// returns True
```

As you can see, `.Equals()` method tells me that the Viewstate object and the List object are the same.
Now my question to you guys is how can a `List` and a `Viewstate` be a reference to the same object? What does the heap memory at that location actually hold?

**Update** 
The code below demonstrates that any variable that gets assigned a cast value of the viewstate, are all pointing to the same object.

```
   List<string> myList1 = new List<string>();
    myList1.Add("apple");
    ViewState["L"] = myList1;

    List<string> myList2 = new List<string>();
    myList2 = (List<string>)ViewState["L"];

    List<string> myList3 = new List<string>();
    myList3 = (List<string>)ViewState["L"];;

    myList3.Add("orange");//Here myList2 gets an orange too !
```

I think, Thomas is right.

Comment: Also, your second line of code overwrites your first line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can a List and a Viewstate be a reference to the same object?

It's not "a ViewState", but an element of the ViewState. `ViewState["L"]` returns an object which is actually a `List<string>` (the same one you just assigned to `myList`)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're talking about `ASP.NET` here. 
Consider that `ViewState` is available on server side, before being trasmitted on client, you reference the exact same object allocated on heap on the server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually a new viewstate object is created after every postback (I verified that doing a gethashcode() ). The question is if I cast that viewstate to something and assign that to a variable, why does that variable point to the Viewstate object? It should point to an object that is a List<string> in this case.

Comment: @user1110437: cause we are talking about a **references** on the *same* object. Casting has no *any* effect here, from the quesiton point of view. The *references* of the both `List<T>` and `ViewState` are compared, so as they point on the same object, `equals=true`. That is.

Answer (score 1):

ViewState is actually an object of type [StateBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.statebag.aspx)

StateBag is just a container of other objects.
the ["L"] in `ViewState["L"]` is an indexer into ViewState that returns some object.  In this case that object is a `List<string>` object

Your `Equals()` comparison is saying that the reference held by `ViewState["L"]` is equal to the reference held by `myList`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You should read on value/reference types and operator precedence http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx.

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
```

Now previous value of myList is gone and replaced by `(ViewState["L"])` cast to `List<string>`:

```
myList=(List<string>)ViewState["L"];
```

Now you compare 2 references to `Object` type (as the only suitable override is `Object.Equals(Object)` ) one myList (which holds `(ViewState["L"])` ) and another `(ViewState["L"])` itself. As result you get `true` for comparison.

```
Response.Write(myList.Equals(ViewState["L"]));// returns True
```